# Invalid block tag: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django

[image]

Given is my folder structure.

In 'home.html':

```
{% extends 'job_main/base.html' %} 
{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %} 
{% block content %}
<h1>Home Page</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

In 'job_main/base.html':

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %} | Jobs Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
.
.
{% block content %} {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

Comment: Also checked other answers which is due to extra space or missing '%' ;but in my case those parts are correct.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], your given example does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: which part you want to know?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeat a block name in the `endblock`. It should be just `{% endblock %}` instead of `{% endblock title %}`.

Comment: yes tried with the same but still the same error.When I remove this part '{% block title %}Home{% endblock %} ' ;it works without it but i want dynamic title.